# SQL query generated by LINQ contains two same SELECTs

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have this simple LINQ, and I can't figure out why resulting SQL is so weird.

This is the LINQ:

```
var query =
(
    from fileRecord in _context.FileRecords
    join linkAttr in _context.LinkAttributes on fileRecord.Id equals linkAttr.FileRecordId
    where linkAttr.ValidTo == null
    join titleAttr in _context.TitleAttributes on fileRecord.Id equals titleAttr.FileRecordId into titleGJ
    join textAttr in _context.TextAttributes on fileRecord.Id equals textAttr.FileRecordId into textGJ
    join publishedAttr in _context.PublishedAttributes on fileRecord.Id equals publishedAttr.FileRecordId into publishedGJ
    select new Set
    {
        Id = fileRecord.Id,
        ParentId = fileRecord.Type == FileRecordType.Photobank ? null : linkAttr.ParentId,
        Title =
        (
            from titleAttr in titleGJ
            where titleAttr.ValidTo == null && titleAttr.CultureId == cultureId
            select titleAttr.Title
        ).FirstOrDefault(),
        Text =
        (
            from textAttr in textGJ
            where textAttr.ValidTo == null && textAttr.CultureId == cultureId
            select textAttr.Text
        ).FirstOrDefault(),
        Published =
        (
            from publishedAttr in publishedGJ
            where publishedAttr.ValidTo == null && publishedAttr.CultureId == cultureId
            select publishedAttr.Published
        ).FirstOrDefault()
    }
);
```

All three entities - in this case TitleAttribute, TextAttribute, and PublishedAttribute are almost the same classes, PublishedAttribute contains one more property, but in the LINQ isn't used.

But generated query is *weird*. The select from PublishedAttributes table is there twice (marked by comments):

```
SELECT 
    [Project12].[Id] AS [Id], 
    CASE WHEN (5 = [Project12].[Type]) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE [Project12].[ParentId] END AS [C1], 
    [Project12].[C1] AS [C2], 
    [Project12].[C2] AS [C3], 
    CASE WHEN ([Project12].[C3] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Project12].[C4] END AS [C4]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project10].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Project10].[Type] AS [Type], 
        [Project10].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
        [Project10].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project10].[C2] AS [C2], 
        [Project10].[C3] AS [C3], 
        -- THIS ONE
        (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent6].[Published] AS [Published]
            FROM [fs].[PublishedAttributes] AS [Extent6]
            WHERE ([Project10].[Id] = [Extent6].[FileRecordId]) AND ([Extent6].[ValidTo] IS NULL) AND ([Extent6].[CultureId] = @p__linq__3)) AS [C4]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project9].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Project9].[Type] AS [Type], 
            [Project9].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
            [Project9].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [Project9].[C2] AS [C2], 
            [Project9].[C3] AS [C3]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project7].[Id] AS [Id], 
                [Project7].[Type] AS [Type], 
                [Project7].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
                [Project7].[C1] AS [C1], 
                [Project7].[C2] AS [C2], 
                -- AND THIS ONE
                (SELECT TOP (1) 
                    [Extent5].[Published] AS [Published]
                    FROM [fs].[PublishedAttributes] AS [Extent5]
                    WHERE ([Project7].[Id] = [Extent5].[FileRecordId]) AND ([Extent5].[ValidTo] IS NULL) AND ([Extent5].[CultureId] = @p__linq__3)) AS [C3]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Project6].[Id] AS [Id], 
                    [Project6].[Type] AS [Type], 
                    [Project6].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
                    [Project6].[C1] AS [C1], 
                    [Project6].[C2] AS [C2]
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        [Project4].[Id] AS [Id], 
                        [Project4].[Type] AS [Type], 
                        [Project4].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
                        [Project4].[C1] AS [C1], 
                        (SELECT TOP (1) 
                            [Extent4].[Text] AS [Text]
                            FROM [fs].[TextAttributes] AS [Extent4]
                            WHERE ([Project4].[Id] = [Extent4].[FileRecordId]) AND ([Extent4].[ValidTo] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[CultureId] = @p__linq__2)) AS [C2]
                        FROM ( SELECT 
                            [Project3].[Id] AS [Id], 
                            [Project3].[Type] AS [Type], 
                            [Project3].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
                            [Project3].[C1] AS [C1]
                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                [Project1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                                [Project1].[Type] AS [Type], 
                                [Project1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId], 
                                (SELECT TOP (1) 
                                    [Extent3].[Title] AS [Title]
                                    FROM [fs].[FileTitleAttributes] AS [Extent3]
                                    WHERE ([Project1].[Id] = [Extent3].[FileRecordId]) AND ([Extent3].[ValidTo] IS NULL) AND ([Extent3].[CultureId] = @p__linq__1)) AS [C1]
                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                                    [Extent1].[Type] AS [Type], 
                                    [Extent2].[ParentId] AS [ParentId]
                                    FROM  [fs].[Files] AS [Extent1]
                                    INNER JOIN [fs].[LinkAttributes] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[FileRecordId]
                                    WHERE ((([Extent1].[BrandId] = @p__linq__0) AND (2 = [Extent1].[Type])) OR (5 = [Extent1].[Type])) AND ([Extent2].[ValidTo] IS NULL)
                                )  AS [Project1]
                            )  AS [Project3]
                        )  AS [Project4]
                    )  AS [Project6]
                )  AS [Project7]
            )  AS [Project9]
        )  AS [Project10]
    )  AS [Project12]
```

In all three tables (TitleAttributes, TextAttributes, and PublishedAttributes), all keys are the same, all indexes are the same, CF EF mapping, all is the same - but I don't get why the generated query contains the same SELECT twice. I'm befuddled and after several hours, clueless.

EF6.1, .NET 4.6.1

EDIT: I found out that if the value I'm selecting is string, the appropriate SELECT is there correctly once. Otherwise, if it's int or bool, it's selected twice. titleAttr.Title and textAttr.Text are strings; publishedAttr.Published is boolean - so it's selected for some reason twice. Weird.

Comment: I haven't traced it (too complex to do quickly) but I'd bet it is because of the three FirstOrDefault() methods when building the return set. Those force it to execute the query a few times to insure a result comes back no matter which results are missing.

Comment: It was my first thought too, so in that LINQ I tried to put that Published = ... to the beginning, to the middle... and those two selects were always there on the same table. In the execution plan that unnecessary subselect costs about 20 %, so it bothers me. But moreover, I'd like to know what's wrong with my understanding of LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I finally discovered/realized that the problem happens when selected value isn't nullable, the answer is here:

```
CASE WHEN ([Project12].[C3] IS NULL) THEN cast(0 as bit) ELSE [Project12].[C4] END AS [C4]
```

It's necessary to find out whether the value is null (first select), if so, return 0, if it's not, return the value (second select).